# jQuery slider touch-punch not working properly

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960553/jquery-slider-range-doesnt-work-on-ipad) and using touch-punch. But, its throwing me the following error:
`Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'` for the line :

```
<script>
$('#slider-range-min').draggable();</script> or <script>$('#widget').draggable();
</script>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The most probable error must be the order in which you referred external resources. Make sure the order is jquery, jquery  UI, then jQuery Touch Punch.

```
<script src="js/jquery.1.9.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```